# property wrappers using members

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

In [Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/ObservedResults.html#/s:10RealmSwift15ObservedResultsV5whereAA5QueryVySbGAFyxGcSgvp) there are Property wrappers such as @ObservedResults that allow querying data using filters such as:

```
@ObservedResults(Dog.self, where: ( { $0.weight > 40 } )) var dogs
```

Assuming I have a member named `minimumWeight`, I'm trying to do something like

```
struct ExampleStruct: View {

   var minWeight: Int  //(or lazy var with an assignment)

   @ObservedResults(Dog.self, where: ( { $0.weight > minWeight } )) var dogs

}
```

Obviously, this code doesn't work because minWeight was not initialized yet but is there any workaround?

The error I'm getting

`Cannot use instance member 'minWeight' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Looking for a solution beside the "Static Variable" solution (`static var minWeight: Int` will probably work)

Comment: So you're attempting to observe the results of a query for changes, correct? Is `minWeight` variable or a static value? At what point do you know what the value of `minWeight` will be?

Comment: on class initialization - Previous View should "supply" this data

Comment: There's a number of options: you could set up an @Environment var and when initializing the view you could do this `ContentView().environmentObject(some var)` or do something in `ContentView().onAppear {...`. There's @State or better yet, initialize it with default value that can be nil `init(someVar: String? = nil`. There's lot of options. Explore those and get back if you have additional difficulty.